# Javascript - Tabs with lists inside content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I'm currently struggling to find a good solution to a very annoying problem.

I'm currently using tabs on my website, these tabs make use of the UL, LI system, as do most tab systems I could find in tutorials.

The main problem is, is the fact that due to the javascript I cannot use the UL, LI system inside my content anymore.

The javascript adds an active class towards a selected tab, and removes it as soon as you switch towards another tab, which forces all LI's to inherit the "display:none;" function.

What would be the best way to go around fixing this?

Here is the javascript part

```
$(function () {
var container = $('.tabs-container'),
    tabs      = container.find('.tabs li'),
    links     = tabs.find('a'),
    contents  = container.find('.contents li');

links.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

tabs.on('click', function () {
    var $this    = $(this),
        $id      = $this.find('a').attr('href'),
        $target  = container.find('.contents ' + $id);

    if ($this.hasClass('active'))
        return;

    tabs.removeClass('active');
    $this.addClass('active');

    contents.removeClass('active').hide();
    $target.fadeIn(500).addClass('active');
});
});
```

I've added a JSFiddle with the code (
https://jsfiddle.net/f6jLt91d/ )

As you can see, the initial tab has a list in there, which displays 'fine' once I added the "display:inline" rule in the style manually, but as soon as you switch to tab 2 and then go back to tab 1 they will disappear.

I'm probably overlooking something really small and silly here but I've been bothered by this for the past 3 days and can't seem to find a solution that fixes this issue, anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be specific with the `CSS` selector, as you have contents with `<li>`. Which is really a LoL. Don't use it. But one of the best code I have seen.

The fix is really simple. Hide only the top level `<li>`s and don't run down the tree. I am changing the selectors to use the child selector here. At first it selects the descendants, which caused the issue.

```
tabs      = container.find('.tabs > li'),
contents  = container.find('.contents > li');
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  var container = $('.tabs-container'),
      tabs      = container.find('.tabs > li'),
      links     = tabs.find('a'),
      contents  = container.find('.contents > li');

  links.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  tabs.on('click', function () {
    var $this    = $(this),
        $id      = $this.find('a').attr('href'),
        $target  = container.find('.contents ' + $id);

    if ($this.hasClass('active'))
      return;

    tabs.removeClass('active');
    $this.addClass('active');

    contents.removeClass('active').hide();
    $target.fadeIn(500).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.tabs-container {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width: 400px;
  float: none;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 0 0 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.tabs-container .tabs,
.tabs-container .contents {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.tabs-container .tabs li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #222;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.tabs-container .tabs li:last-child { margin-right: 0; }

.tabs-container .tabs li:hover {
  background: #111;
}

.tabs-container .tabs li.active {
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 17px;
  background: #000;
}

.tabs-container .tabs li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;

}

.tabs-container .tabs li.active a,
.tabs-container .tabs li:hover a {
    color: #888;
}

/* Tab Contents */

.tabs-container .contents {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding: 20px;
  top: 53px;
  left: 0;
  background: #222;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius:5px;
}

.tabs-container .contents li {
    display: none;
}

.tabs-container .contents li.active {
    display: block;
    color:#FFF;
}

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs-container">
  <ul class="tabs cf">
    <li class="active"><a href="#one">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#three">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#four">Tab 4</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="contents cf">
    <li id="one" class="active">
      <ul>
        <li style="display:inline;">Testing</li>
        <li style="display:inline;">Testing</li>
        <li style="display:inline;">Testing</li>
        <li style="display:inline;">Testing</li>
        <li style="display:inline;">Testing</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="two">
      Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing 
    </li>
    <li id="three">
      Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing 
    </li>
    <li id="four">
      Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/engcr3qp/**

Comment: I feel slightly embarassed for forgetting all about the ">" part.
Thank you so much, this made it work all smoothly.

I'll upvote once I can. :)